# gcc/msvc compile the following, clang does not. Is there a workaround?

Tags: c++, vector, clang, constexpr, variant

```c++
#include <optional>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

// A
static_assert(
    std::optional<
        std::vector< int >
    >{ std::vector< int >{ 1, 2, 3 } }
);
// B
static_assert(
    std::optional<
        std::variant<
            std::vector< int >
        >
    >{ std::vector< int >{ 1, 2, 3 } }
);
```

https://godbolt.org/z/jbdfPYqe1

These samples do not compile using clang (18).
They do compile using gcc/msvc.

What exactly causes this behavior and is there a workaround?

Comment: isnt the error message explaining the reason?

Comment: The error is clear in the sense that it explains why clang cannot compile it. It does not help in explaining why both gcc and msvc can compile it just fine. I believe clang is diverting from the standard, but I am not sure.

Comment: your comparison isnt sound. You compile clang C++17 and gcc C++20.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai True, but error is the same in C++20: https://godbolt.org/z/fMo45nnKK

Comment: please include the compiler error message in the question. Not including it in the question is potential confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Now, I haven't found the exact information in the clang documentation yet, but I am assuming that what you are trying to do is not yet supported by Clang. Although Clang is slowly starting to support C++ 20, it is only doing so [partially](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#cxx20), and I am assuming that what you are trying to do has not yet become supported.